# Getting the width of the left most column header (but it really isn't a real column header)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, datagridview

In a datagridview, the left most column is just a blank column, and it can't be accessed using dgv.Columns[columnNumber].  To get its with, what I'm doing is taking the width of the entire datagridview, and subtracting the width of each real column.  There is a problem when there is a vertical scroll bar, so I have code that accounts for this if there is one.

I feel like I'm going through too much trouble to find this value and was wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to get at it based on an Index..?? just curious..

Comment: By index, do you mean, dgv.Columns[columnNumber]?  If not, can you please explain how you would do this? I'm not familiar with this method.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes.. I've seen something like this before where their can be hidden columns .you can try it..

Comment: Do you mean the (gray) RowHeader? That is RowHeaderSize pixels wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
datagrid.RowHeadersWidth
```